# Keep values from SQL 'IN' Operator

Tags: sql

How to modify query

```
SELECT field1, field2 FROM table1 WHERE field1 IN ('value1', 'value2', 'value3');
```

to get `NULL` as **field2**  if  *'value2'* not found?

**Table1:**

```
field1 | field2
-------+--------
value1 | result1
value3 | result3
value4 | result4
```

**Current output:**

```
field1 | field2
-------+--------
value1 | result1
value3 | result3
```

**Expected output:**

```
field1 | field2
-------+-------
value1 | result1
value2 | NULL
value3 | result3
```

Comment: Your current query already is doing this.  What is the actual question?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, No, this query excludes not found values.

Comment: Show us by way of current and expected output what you mean.

Comment: @TimBiegelsen I can lend you some coffee if you've run out.

Comment: You are using postgresql, not mysql right?

Comment: is there more than one table?

Comment: I removed the incompatible database clauses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an *LEFT JOIN* against a table containing the 'full output set'. The `IN` clause (really, any condition in `WHERE`) *can only filter/remove* results: it can *never* add new records.

Depends on flavor of SQL; an example:

```
SELECT
   fullSet.field1,
   t.field2
FROM (SELECT 'value1' as field1 -- set of rows value1..4
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 'value2'
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 'value3'
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 'value4') fullSet
LEFT JOIN table1 t              -- join to access t.field2 (null if no match)
  ON t.field1 = fullSet.field1
WHERE t.field1 IN ('value1', 'value2', 'value3'); -- filtered value4
```

Different SQL dialects may provide more convenient methods of building up the entire result set space (eg. CTEs in SQL Server).

Comment: while I think this may be correct, the question suggests there is just a single table. IF **field2** comes from a **table2** then using a left join for table2 would allow the wanted result.

Comment: One thing I'm trying to use SO for is to check my ideas out, and as I came up with the same solution prior to looking at the answers gives me some sort of acknowledgement that I can work some of these problems out.

Comment: @user2864740 Works as expected! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Postgres, then I would write this as:

```
SELECT v.field1, t1.field2
FROM (VALUES ('value1'), ('value2'), ('value3')) v(field1) LEFT JOIN
     table1 t1
     ON t1.field1 = v.field1;
```

If you are using MySQL, the answer is similar, but the construct fort he first table looks a bit different:

```
SELECT v.field1, t1.field2
FROM (SELECT 'value1' as field1 UNION ALL
      SELECT 'value2' as field1 UNION ALL
      SELECT 'value3' as field1 
     ) v LEFT JOIN
     table1 t1
     ON t1.field1 = v.field1;
```

In neither case do you need a `WHERE` clause.